# Discord.py make survey form like picture how

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[image]

I need to make python survey bot discord like in picture and I don't know how

Answer (score 1):

The type of Survey Form that you want to create is of the type called Modal

A step-by-step guide on how to setup a similar survey form is provided here: https://autocode.com/app/janethl/discord-modal-surveys/

Basically you can call a slash command that would output the modal along with all the questions in the feedback survey form

You can watch a Youtube Video Guide too on how to create a feedback survey form like that for Discord: https://youtu.be/LuuogF0yxvA

Total Two API Integrations are Available:

1. Through Discord: https://autocode.com/lib/discord/
2. Through Google Sheets: https://autocode.com/lib/googlesheets/

A prebuilt Discord Example app is available here: https://autocode.com/app/janethl/discord-modal-surveys/

Comment: The Source code is available too if someone wants to build from scratch following along the illustrative guide: https://autocode.com/app/janethl/discord-modal-surveys/src/

Comment: Thanks for linking the source code, it can be found on the same guide page too.

Comment: Having code in an off-site resource is not good practice in answer. Answers should be self-contained. You can quote the resources (with attribution) and you can definitely leave the links as external resources. However, as it is, this answer does not answer the question of how to make a discord.py bot to use modals.